# how does the store request for delivery using (UberRush)

Tags: uber-api

I am looking to integrate UberRush API to our website, once the order has been placed online and the store has made the item ready to be shipped , how does the store request for delivery(I mean from Uber website or retailers website/app?) and when they request for delivery how do we know which order they want the delivery for, is there any interconnecting link between the delivery requested and the order placed by customer?

Thank you..!!

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for UberRUSH API is here: https://developer.uber.com/docs/deliveries/introduction

It looks like you have general questions which should be answered by going through that documentation. Stack Overflow is better for specific technical programming questions. If you have more general non-technical questions about Uber API, I suggest posting on the community forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/uber-developers